# Skip entity validation on form

Tags: drupal, hook, drupal-8

I would like to not have the entity validation of the default password change form. When the form is validated, I just want to redirect the user without having the entity validation.

Is it possible to bypass it ?

```php
function alter_form_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
{
      if ($form_id == 'user_form') {
        $form['#validate'] = ['update_validate'];
        $form['#submit'][] = 'update_custom_submit_method';
    }
}

function update_custom_submit_method(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
}

function update_validate(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
  //the form is validated -> redirect//
}
```